# How to apply Gradient color set as background view Horizontally?

Tags: android

I need to set Gradient color background view horizontally this is my shape code

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient     
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#E58300"
        android:endColor="#DD3D01"
        android:startColor="#D22604"
        android:type="linear"></gradient>            
        <corners 
        android:radius="90dp"/>    
</shape>
```

This is shown background view Like Top to bottom.I want gradient color to apply like left to Right in a background view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the angle at 180.
`android:angle="180"`

Answer (score 2):

Make the `android:angle` to 0. to so that it will rotate to left to right.

```
<gradient android:angle="0" android:centerColor="#E58300" android:startColor="#D22604" android:endColor="#DD3D01" android:type="linear" />
```